# replacing makedepend with cc -MM

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I currently use makedepend, but it I ran into some problems with it and a library and decided I might as well switch to `cc -MM`. My current makefile is modelled off of [this](https://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/software-engineering/how-to-write-a-makefile).

How would I go about making the change?

---

## Current Makefile

```
NAME := engine
C_SRCS := $(wildcard *.c) $(wildcard */*.c)
H_SRCS := $(wildcard *.h) $(wildcard */*.h)
C_OBJS := ${C_SRCS:.c=.o}
INCLUDE_DIRS := .
LIBRARY_DIRS :=
LIBRARIES := event

CFLAGS += $(foreach includedir,$(INCLUDE_DIRS),-I$(includedir))
LDFLAGS += $(foreach librarydir,$(LIBRARY_DIRS),-L($librarydir))
LDFLAGS += $(foreach library,$(LIBRARIES),-l$(library))

.PHONY: all clean depend

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(C_OBJS)
    $(LINK.cc) $(C_OBJS) -o $(NAME)

clean:
    @- $(RM) $(NAME)
    @- $(RM) $(OBJS)

distclean: clean

depend:
    makedepend -- $(CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -- $(C_SRCS)

# makedepend after this line
# DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE

engine.o: util/std.h /usr/include/stdlib.h /usr/include/Availability.h
engine.o: /usr/include/AvailabilityInternal.h /usr/include/_types.h
engine.o: /usr/include/sys/_types.h /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h
engine.o: /usr/include/machine/_types.h /usr/include/i386/_types.h
engine.o: /usr/include/sys/wait.h /usr/include/sys/signal.h
engine.o: /usr/include/sys/appleapiopts.h /usr/include/machine/signal.h
engine.o: /usr/include/i386/signal.h /usr/include/i386/_structs.h
engine.o: /usr/include/sys/_structs.h /usr/include/machine/_structs.h
engine.o: /usr/include/sys/resource.h /usr/include/machine/endian.h
engine.o: /usr/include/i386/endian.h /usr/include/sys/_endian.h
engine.o: /usr/include/libkern/_OSByteOrder.h
engine.o: /usr/include/libkern/i386/_OSByteOrder.h /usr/include/alloca.h
engine.o: /usr/include/machine/types.h /usr/include/i386/types.h util/out.h
engine.o: /usr/include/stdio.h /usr/include/secure/_stdio.h
engine.o: /usr/include/secure/_common.h /usr/include/errno.h
engine.o: /usr/include/sys/errno.h /usr/include/string.h
engine.o: /usr/include/secure/_string.h util/lvl.h conf.h http/server.h
http/server.o: /usr/include/errno.h /usr/include/sys/errno.h
http/server.o: /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h /usr/include/stdlib.h
http/server.o: /usr/include/Availability.h
http/server.o: /usr/include/AvailabilityInternal.h /usr/include/_types.h
http/server.o: /usr/include/sys/_types.h /usr/include/machine/_types.h
http/server.o: /usr/include/i386/_types.h /usr/include/sys/wait.h
http/server.o: /usr/include/sys/signal.h /usr/include/sys/appleapiopts.h
http/server.o: /usr/include/machine/signal.h /usr/include/i386/signal.h
http/server.o: /usr/include/i386/_structs.h /usr/include/sys/_structs.h
http/server.o: /usr/include/machine/_structs.h /usr/include/sys/resource.h
http/server.o: /usr/include/machine/endian.h /usr/include/i386/endian.h
http/server.o: /usr/include/sys/_endian.h /usr/include/libkern/_OSByteOrder.h
http/server.o: /usr/include/libkern/i386/_OSByteOrder.h /usr/include/alloca.h
http/server.o: /usr/include/machine/types.h /usr/include/i386/types.h
http/server.o: /usr/include/unistd.h /usr/include/sys/unistd.h
http/server.o: /usr/include/sys/select.h /usr/include/sys/_select.h
http/server.o: /usr/include/sys/socket.h /usr/include/sys/types.h
http/server.o: /usr/include/machine/_param.h /usr/include/i386/_param.h
http/server.o: /usr/include/netdb.h /usr/include/stdint.h
http/server.o: /usr/include/netinet/in.h /usr/include/netinet6/in6.h
http/server.o: /usr/include/arpa/inet.h /usr/include/fcntl.h
http/server.o: /usr/include/sys/fcntl.h http/request.h conf.h util/out.h
http/server.o: /usr/include/stdio.h /usr/include/secure/_stdio.h
http/server.o: /usr/include/secure/_common.h /usr/include/string.h
http/server.o: /usr/include/secure/_string.h util/lvl.h util/buf.h
http/server.o: /usr/include/stddef.h
util/buf.o: /usr/include/stdlib.h /usr/include/Availability.h
util/buf.o: /usr/include/AvailabilityInternal.h /usr/include/_types.h
util/buf.o: /usr/include/sys/_types.h /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h
util/buf.o: /usr/include/machine/_types.h /usr/include/i386/_types.h
util/buf.o: /usr/include/sys/wait.h /usr/include/sys/signal.h
util/buf.o: /usr/include/sys/appleapiopts.h /usr/include/machine/signal.h
util/buf.o: /usr/include/i386/signal.h /usr/include/i386/_structs.h
util/buf.o: /usr/include/sys/_structs.h /usr/include/machine/_structs.h
util/buf.o: /usr/include/sys/resource.h /usr/include/machine/endian.h
util/buf.o: /usr/include/i386/endian.h /usr/include/sys/_endian.h
util/buf.o: /usr/include/libkern/_OSByteOrder.h
util/buf.o: /usr/include/libkern/i386/_OSByteOrder.h /usr/include/alloca.h
util/buf.o: /usr/include/machine/types.h /usr/include/i386/types.h util/buf.h
util/buf.o: /usr/include/stddef.h util/std.h util/out.h /usr/include/stdio.h
util/buf.o: /usr/include/secure/_stdio.h /usr/include/secure/_common.h
util/buf.o: /usr/include/errno.h /usr/include/sys/errno.h
util/buf.o: /usr/include/string.h /usr/include/secure/_string.h util/lvl.h
util/buf.o: conf.h
```

Comment: This will be tricky; `cc -M` generates a dependency list as standard output (which can be redirected into a file), whereas makedepend actually inserts it into the makefile by default. Maybe you could post a small makefile, and we could show you how to change it.

Comment: With the `.PHONY` target, you are probably using GNU Make, but it no bad thing to be explicit about such issues.  There are other versions of `make` out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the last section of this page on [auto-dependencies](http://make.paulandlesley.org/autodep.html).

If your compiler supports the -MMD option (like gcc does), then you just include -MMD (make dependencies) and -MP (make phony targets for each prereq in a .d file) in your compiler flags, and add the following to the end of your Makefile:

```
# Use the dependency files created by the -MMD option to gcc.
-include $(SRCS:.c=.d)
```

I've been using this for awhile with Cygwin/gcc and have been happy with the results.

Comment: Given the the questioner is probably using GNU Make (because of the `.PHONY` target), then the solution with the `-include` should be OK too.  That is, AFAIK, a GNU Make feature, though - not standardized.

Comment: Where should the dependency generation go? I know it should be somewhere in the `%.o: %.c[pp]`-rule, but a copy-paste recipe would be appreciated.

Comment: BTW, here is a (subjectively) easier description for this "autodependencies": http://scottmcpeak.com/autodepend/autodepend.html

Comment: @TomaszGandor, I'm pretty sure the lines quoted in my answer can go anywhere in the Makefile.  In my case, I place them right before the `%.o: %.c[pp]`-rule, but it's not actually a part of it.